# getUuid() returns null for BLE?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to connect my BLE to my phone. But I get 'null' when I call 'getUuid()'. Interestingly, everything works fine when I try it with a Bluetooth instead of Bluetooth Low Energy.

Any one knows why?

I'm developing on Android Studio.

Comment: Are you running on the API 23 phone/emulator?

Comment: I'm running the app on my Nexus 5 phone.

Comment: That doesn't automatically define Android version, as Nexus 5 got updates. If it really has Android M, then [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182219/android-marshmallow-api-23-bluetooth-uuid-returns-null) you will get answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample code that one may find very useful for scanning and connecting to BLE.

Apparently, the function calls for BLE and Bluetooth are different. UUID is not how we connect to Bluetooth. Different functions are to be used.

http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-bluetooth-low-energy-ble-example/